# How to keep a user logged in after page refresh

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt

I have a simple web application that a user can create an account and login ... whenever a user log in i am generating a `json-web-token` for him and storing it on his database object ... im using that `token` to authenticate the user when he visits certain routes ( Bearer token on the header ) but the problem is that when the user refreshes the page i lose that token and he have to provide the email and password again to generate another token ... i was thinking about using `localStorage` or `cookies` but maybe there is a better / commonly used way for this ... any advises would be helpful thanks .

```js
router.post('/user/login' ,async (req,res)=>{
    try {
        const user = await User.findByCredentials(req.body.email,req.body.password)
        const token = await user.generateToken()
        res.send({ user, token })
    } catch(e) {
        res.status(404).send(e)
    }
})
```

```js
axios({
  method: "post",
  url: "/api/user/login",
  data: {
    email: email,
    password: password
  }
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The traditional way to use Persistent session(**remember me** feature) is to use cookies.

You can make set the max age lets say 30 days when logging in.

```
router.post('/user/login', function(req, res) {
    ....
    req.session.cookie.maxAge = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // Cookie expires after 30 days
    ....
});
```

The logical flow should be:

1. When the user successfully logs, a login cookie is issued.
2. It should contain some kind of token which you then need to **HASH**(`hash(cookie)`) and store it in DB.
3. When a non-logged-in user visits the site and presents a login cookie, the series identifier is looked up in the database.
4. If it finds the cookie it gets authenticated, otherwise asks to login.

Comment: Thanks that's what i was aiming for ... just concerning "It should contain some kind of token which you then need to HASH".... the token is already encrypted (jwt) do i have to hash it also ?

Comment: A token is equivalent to a password(even jwt) . So, basically if the db is compromised the token will be exposed. that's why you should hash it.

Answer (score 0):

Start the session on the first line of your page, and store the login credentials in it. You can do the same for all other pages to be accessed after login.